# Como posso printar um variável de dentro do script do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

A dúvida é exatamente como posso fazer para "printar" um valor de dentro do meu código JavaScript para que eu possa acompanhar se a variável tem o valor correto.

Eu estou aprendendo JavaScript na faculdade e estava escrevendo um trabalho que leva o código a baixo. No entanto após alguns erros resolvi testa um dos módulos a fim de verificar o valor calculado. Mas aí veio outro problema que é de não saber como posso "printar" esse valor no código para que eu possa visualizar em meu navegador.

ImpostoDeRenda

```
        <h1>Cálculo do Imposto de Renda</h1>

        <br>
        Contribuição previdenciaria: <input type="text" name="contribuicao" id="contribuicaoId">
        <br>
        Despesas medicas:<input type="text" name="despesas" id="despesasId">
        <br>
        Número de dependentes: <input type="text" name="dependentes" id="dependentesId">
        <br>        
        Enviar: <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="deducao()">


        <script language="JavaScript">
        function deducao(){
                var dedu;
                var contribuicao=parseInt(getElementById("contribuicaoId").value,10);
                var despesas=parseInt(getElementById("despesasId").value,10);
                var dependentes=parseInt(getElementById("dependentesId").value,10);

            dedu=contribuicao+despesas+dependentes*3050;
            document.write("Resposta:" +dedu);
    }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Se for só pra fins de debug você pode usar console.log(NomeDaVariavelAqui) nas partes do código onde você quer acompanhar o valor, aí pra visualizar é só apertar F12 com o seu site rodando e vai aparecer na seção "console" da janela que abrir. Outra alternativa é apertar novamente F12 e colocar uma linha debugger; no seu código para parar o seu programa, aí com f10 você pode ir executando linha por linha visualizando como o valor da variável que quer acompanhar muda na janela que o F12 abriu, nesse caso é só colocar o mouse em cima da variável onde ela aparecer no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a função `console.log()` para apresentar seu valor no console do navegador. Aperte F12 no navegador, em seguida clique na aba `console` e o valor será apresentado no console do navegador.

Exemplo de utilização:

```
var valor = 10;
console.log('O valor é: ' + valor);
```

> **Imagem de exemplo do console do navegador**
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione nos pontos do seu código que você precisa analisar e vá acompanhando pelo console do navegador.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá, então fiz como você falou. No entanto está dando um erro de uncaght reference. Logo na linha: var contribuicao=parseInt(getElementById("contribuicaoId").value,10); 
obs:Acredito que está linha esteja correta.

Comment: Você está tentando recuperar um elemento pelo `id` dele, porém a função se chama `document.getElementById()`. Tente da seguinte forma: `var contribuicao = parseInt(document.getElementById("contribuicaoId").value,10);`

Comment: Achei o erro. Estava em document.getElementById.....Onde eu por algum motivo omiti o "document."  =S

Answer (score 1):

Utilize `console.log()`, isso irá printar no console do navegador que pode ser acessado usando o F12 (procure pela aba 'Console')